# Create different result set using one result set

Tags: mysql, sql

By using mysql, I got result like

```
    count   date        content
    19      2015-01-02  test1
    6       2015-01-02  test2
    3       2015-01-03  test3
    12      2015-01-04  test4
    48      2015-01-04  test5
    10      2015-01-05  test6
```

I want to divide that result in different result set using date value. I want result set like,

```
    count   date        content
    19      2015-01-02  test1
    6       2015-01-02  test2

    count   date        content
    3       2015-01-03  test3
    12      2015-01-03  test4

    count   date        content
    48      2015-01-04  test5
    10      2015-01-04  test6
```

Is it possible to create different result set using one result set.

Comment: Please mention the real use case of this. Hope there would be different (better) solution to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a resultset in a query condition for a set of queries you need a cursor.

Please check out basics of cursor usage [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor) and in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE group_results_by_date 
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE cdate DATE DEFAULT "2015-01-01";

 -- declare cursor for getting list of dates
 DEClARE date_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT (date) FROM yourtable;

 -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

 OPEN date_cursor;

 get_content: LOOP

 FETCH date_cursor INTO cdate;

 IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_content;
 END IF;

 -- Select query for different dates
 Select count, date, content from yourtable where date = cdate;

 END LOOP get_content;

 CLOSE date_cursor;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can call this procedure by

```
CALL group_results_by_date();
```