# How can I get total count of result sets in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

In Yii Framework I call SQL procedure getData() and I got multiple result sets using following code.

```
     $resultSets = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("call getData()")->query();
```

How can I get total count of result sets which I got in $resultSets. Any other suggestion so I can loop this as per result sets count.

Follow this for details [My Procedure which generate result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841255/create-different-result-set-using-one-result-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count($resultSets)` returns you size of `$resultSets`.

Comment: I don't want to  find count of rows in current result set. The procedure generate multiple result set as per date. This menace if I have two dates in columns then it generate two result sets if three then generate three  result sets and so on. I want that result set count.